# What's the antonym of miss, as in "I miss something"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Is there an antonym for **miss** in the context of "missing" something?

If a person were happy that something were gone, is there an appropriate single word?

I've arrived at "they are glad it's gone", but was curious if there is a single word?

> *Example:*
>
> A character in a story has a parasite for a long period of time.  The parasite is removed and the character exclaims "I ____ the parasite".  They are stating that they are pleased the parasite is gone; the opposite of "I miss the parasite".  "Don't miss" does not convey the pleasure of being free of said parasite.  Miss has an emotion component, where that the opposite should convey.

This question has been answered for the [Alternate definitions of missing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32248/synonyms-and-antonyms-for-lacking-or-missing-when-something-is-mandatory).

Comment: Miss the parasite like a hole in the head.

Answer (score 2):

You could say, ***Good riddance [to the damn thing]!***

> good riddance!
>
> *Cliché* [It is] good to be rid (of worthless persons or things). (also, ***Goodbye and good riddance***) *She slammed the door behind me and said, "Good riddance to bad rubbish!" "Good riddance to you, Ma'am," thought I.*
> McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs
>
> I'm happy that someone or something is gone : *Peter and his nasty dog have finally moved out. Good riddance!* Usage notes: the full form
> of the phrase is [*good riddance to bad rubbish/rubbage*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=riddance+to+bad+rubbage%2Criddance+to+bad+rubbish+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Criddance%20to%20bad%20rubbage%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Criddance%20to%20bad%20rubbish%3B%2Cc0), which
> is sometimes used. [Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/good+riddance)

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a single verb that would convey the full meaning you're looking for but, since you seem to want to express the sense of relief that the change brings, maybe you could use:

> I am relieved that the parasite is gone.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can think of is the word dread as in "I dreaded that parasite"

Or maybe simply use "don't miss" as in "I don't miss that parasite"